# Connecting to Activemq with SSL

Tags: java, ssl, activemq-classic

I'm trying to connect to our ActiveMQ Server as a Message Receiver. First I've tried to connect to a local ActiveMQ, which I downloaded for test purposes. That has worked, the connection worked with the following:

```
private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);   
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
```

Now I need to connect to our ActiveMQ on a server and I need to use SSL. I already imported our .crt key into Java (cacert) but don't know, how to proceed. I guess I have to change the `url` to something like this:

```
url = "failover://ssl://<servername>:61617";
```

But this alone won't work. Does anyone have any tips, how to get the connection? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

```
ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory(url);
connectionFactory.setTrustStore("truststore.ts");
connectionFactory.setTrustStorePassword("password");

Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
```

You just have to create a truststore with your CA.